# Is there a #define _KEYWORD_ for CXXTEST compiler to exclude blocks of code?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cxxtest

I need to temporarily put a `main()` function in my object to test alternate functionality (beyond a simple unit test), but I keep having to comment out my `main()` function to run my unit tests.

Is there a `#define _KEYWORD_` for CxxTest to allow this to happen automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to encapsulate the offending code with a compiler directive based on the definition of the `CXXTEST_RUNNING` keyword.

For example:

```
class myClass {
  public:
    myClass () {}
};

#ifndef CXXTEST_RUNNING
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Temporary runner. Typically deleted upon completion
  // of alternate functionality added later in the project.
}
#endif
```

In this case, when using the CxxTest framework the `main()` function will be ignored in favor of the `main()` created by the testing framework. Otherwise, the `main()` function you have provided will be used.

Comment: Good answer.  I've added documentation in the CxxTest User Manual describing this example.